# Which extra settings in Xcode are applied when Archiving?

Tags: ios, xcode

I have an iOS project. In response to Build (with a release configuration selected in the scheme) the dsym for it weighs in at 6.5MB. However, when I Archive (with the same configuration selected in the scheme) it weighs in at only 2.9MB.

This is not an academic problem. The missing data includes all the symbols for my static libraries, which is making my crash logs a lot less useful.

Which settings could account for a difference between a Build and Archive with the same configuration selected?

This is with Xcode 5.0, though I think I've been having this problem for a while.

Comment: It would be interesting to know, +1 for good question.

Comment: Have you tried building an archive under debug build configuration? (in the scheme settings, under archive)

Comment: So when you re-symbolicate the crash logs on the same computer that built the archive, it only re-symbolicates your code and not the code from your third party libraries? Can you post an example?

Comment: It doesn't symbolicate my code in libraries, either. Just the code in the main project. I'll work up an example this week to add to this question.

Answer (score 1):

I believe a few things it does are:

- Remove all debugging symbols from the app to the .dsym file
- Compresses various articles from ascii to binary (such as strings
  files)

Some of the differences may be from the following build flags:

- DEPLOYMENT_POSTPROCESSING=YES
- STRIP_INSTALLED_PRODUCT=YES
- SEPARATE_STRIP=YES
- COPY_PHASE_STRIP=YES